# Dropdownlist goes to default value after selecting another value

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, detailview

I have created a dropdownlist in Visual Studio 2010. I have code setup such that when I click on a certain value in the list, textboxes become visible. Then, I can insert values into the textboxes, click insert, and the values will be stored into my database.

The Problem:
      My dropdownlist has the values (in order: "Select A Value", "Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3".
When selecting Value 1, the correct textboxes appear underneath the dropdownlist, but the value of the dropdownlist defaults to "Select A Value". Thus, when I insert my data, "Select A Value" appears in my database (BAD!!). The only way I have found to fix this is to click on a value twice. Only then does the dropdownlist value stay as the value selected.
I would like to click on the dropdownlist value only ONCE, and have the value stay set. What am I not doing correctly?
Thank you!!!

Comment: can you please show what your code looks like and how you are filling the dropdowns also show the `Page_Load` code if this a web app.. very hard to provide a valid answer based on the explanation you have given

Comment: All hail the might splat of text, could you please supply supporting code and possibly format your question better so as to enable a better analysis and answer environment for you.

Comment: Firstly, Wow... Secondly, you must be posting back when the selection is being changed and executing code that rebinds that dropdown and selects the first item by default. Please try "debugging" with some "breakpoints"

Comment: Ps "Validation" is also useful to ensure that "BAD" data doesn't get saved to your database

Answer (score 0):

Without the actual code, it's hard to pinpoint what the problem is so I am just giving you my best guess here...

You're probably rebinding the datasource of your dropdownlist on page load or somewhere else. In your Page_Load event, bind the items like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.initialize();
    }
}

private void initialize()
{
    // populate the items of your dropdownlist here!
}
```